# Efficiently finding congruencies

Tags: modular-arithmetic

All variables are integers with a value somewhere between 0-99, inclusive.

ax + b % 100 = n and you are given everything except x.

Example: 65x + 6 is congruent with 81 mod 100.

I am trying to find a way to determine the potentially valid values of x without resorting to brute force.  Is there a known method more efficient than brute force for a problem like this?  If so, can anyone explain how the congruencies are found and/or possibly point me in the direction of any tutorials, books, or videos?

Comment: $65x+6\equiv81\bmod100\implies65x\equiv75\bmod100\implies13x\equiv15\bmod20\implies7x\equiv5\bmod20\implies$ $x\equiv3\times7x\equiv3\times5=15\bmod20$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to your question has a very easy part and a hard part.  First, the very easy part.  You pose
$$  a x + b \cong n \pmod{100}  $$
with the example
$$  65 x + 6 \cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{.}  $$
The basic strategy is the same one you would use if not reduction modulo $100$ were intended: use algebra to solve for $x$.  The first step is very easy, subtract the constant from both sides.
\begin{align*}
a x &\cong n - b\pmod{100}  \\
65 x &\cong 81 - 6  \\
    &\cong 75 \pmod{100}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
(I suspect that you will like to remember, if the result of this subtraction is negative, to add the modulus to the difference to get a result in the interval $[0,100)$ again.)

Now our strategy calls for division by $65$, but there is a "simpler" problem hiding in your example : $65$, $75$, and $100$ have a common factor, $5$, and we can reduce by this common factor.
$$  13 x \cong 15 \pmod{20}  \text{.}  $$
More generally, if $a$ and the modulus, $100$ have a common factor then either $n-b$ also shares that factor and there is a solution or $n-b$ does not share that factor and there is no solution.  So we check that any common factor of $a$ and $100$, $d$, is also a factor of $n-b$.  Having factored $d$ out, we have
$$  (a/d)x \cong (n-b)/d \pmod{100/d}  \text{.}  $$
The easiest way to compute $d$ is using the Euclidean algorithm to compute the greatest common divisor (gcd) of $a$ and $100$.  Having found and divided out the greatest common divisor, we know that $a/d$ and $100/d$ are relatively prime.  This ensures that there is a number, $c$, such that
$$  c \cdot (a/d) \cong 1 \pmod{100/d}  \text{,} $$
That is, $c$ acts like the reciprocal of the coefficient of $x$, so multplying by $c$ is like dividing by that coefficient.

How do we find this $c$?  Use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).  The input is two integers, $a/d$ and $100/d$, whose gcd you want to know.  The output is that gcd and also a pair of numbers, $e$ and $f$, with the following immediately useful property:
$$  e \cdot (a/d) + f \cdot (100/d) = \gcd(a/d,100/d) = 1  \text{.}  $$
That is $e$ and $f$ are coefficients for each input that act like their reciprocals when using the other input as modulus.  For us, we want $e$ and we multiply both sides of the equation by $e$:
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{e \cdot (a/d)}_{\cong 1 \pmod{100/d}} x &\cong e \cdot (n-b)/d \pmod{100/d}  \\
x &\cong e \cdot (n-b)/d \pmod{100/d}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
What does the computation of $e$look like in the example?  We want to study the gcd of $13$ and $20$.
\begin{align*}
20 &= 1 \cdot 13 + 7  &  7 &= 1 \cdot 20 - 1 \cdot 13  \\
13 &= 1 \cdot 7 + 6  &  6 &= -1 \cdot 20 + 2 \cdot 13  \\
7 &= 1 \cdot 6 + 1  &  1 &= (7-6) = 2 \cdot 20 -3 \cdot 13  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
(In the last line, we have reminded that the multiples of $20$ and $13$ we need are present on prior lines.)

This says that $2$ is the reciprocal of $20$ modulo $13$ and also that $-3$ is the reciprocal of $13$ modulo $20$.  We want the latter and we add the modulus, $20$, to it to get a small positive number.
$$  17 \cdot 13 \cong 1 \pmod{20}  $$
So,
\begin{align*}
17 \cdot 13 x &\cong 17 \cdot 15 \pmod{20}  \\
x &\cong 17 \cdot 15 \pmod{20}  \\
x &\cong 15 \pmod{20}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

If it had been the case that $d = 1$, so we were not working with a reduced modulus, we would be done.  However, when $d > 1$ there are multiple solutions.  We know that $15$ is one solution and we know that $15$ plus multiples of $20$ are solutions.  Since the original congruence is modulo $100$, we want to know all the "$15$ plus multiples of $20$" in $[0,100)$.  (By division, there are $100/20 = 5$, and in general, there are $d$ of them, but let's write them down.)
They are $15$, $35$, $55$, $75$, and $95$.  (If we add $20$ again, we "wrap around" back to $15$.)

Let's test these:
\begin{align*}
65(15) + 6 &\cong 975 + 6 \\
    &\cong 981  \\
    &\cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{,}  \\
65(35) + 6 &\cong 2275 + 6 \\
    &\cong 2281  \\
    &\cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{,}  \\
65(55) + 6 &\cong 3575 + 6 \\
    &\cong 3581  \\
    &\cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{,}  \\
65(75) + 6 &\cong 4875 + 6 \\
    &\cong 4881  \\
    &\cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{, and}  \\
65(95) + 6 &\cong 6175 + 6 \\
    &\cong 6181  \\
    &\cong 81 \pmod{100}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
This shows that all the numbers we found are solutions.  The argument laid out above shows that these are all of them.

Answer (score -1):

$65x+6\equiv81\bmod100\iff65x\equiv75\bmod100\iff$

$13x\equiv15\bmod20\iff7x\equiv5\bmod20\iff x\equiv3\times7x\equiv3\times5=15\bmod20$

Answer (score -1):

$ax + b \equiv c\pmod{f} \iff ax \equiv (c-b) \pmod{f}.$

Therefore, the **general** problem reduces to attacking

$$a(x) \equiv e \pmod{f}, ~\text{where}~ a,e,f 
~\text{are known integers}.$$

Suppose that $d =$ gcd$(a,f).$  If $d$ does not divide $e$, then the problem has no solution.  If $d$ does divide $e$, then the problem is equivalent to

$$\frac{a}{d}(x) \equiv \frac{e}{d} \pmod{\frac{f}{d}}.$$

Therefore, WLOG, $a,f$ are relatively prime and the general problem to solve is

$$a(x) \equiv e \pmod{f}.$$

One approach to attack this general problem is compute $s$ such that $a(s) \equiv 1\pmod{f}.$  Since $a,f$ are relatively prime, $s$ must exist.

Once $s$ is computed, then you have

$$x \equiv [a(s)](x) \equiv e(s) \pmod{f}.$$

Therefore, the solution will be $x \equiv e(s) \pmod{f}.$

One standard way to compute $s$ is via the Euclidean algorithm.

The easiest way to demonstrate this is by example.

Let $a = 53, f = 75$.

Then $75 = 53(1) + 22.$ 
$53 = 22(2) + 9.$ 
$22 = 9(2) + 4.$ 
$9 = 4(2) + 1.$

Therefore: 
$1 = 9 - 4(2)$ 
$= 9 - (2)[22 - 9(2)] = 9(5) - 22(2)$ 
$= 22(-2) + (5)[53 - 22(2)] = 53(5) - 22(12)$ 
$= 53(5) - (12)[75 - 53] = 53(17) - 75(12).$

Therefore, $(53 \times 17) \equiv 1\pmod{75}.$